# CSS Menu example adding another submenu

Tags: css, html

I found this really cool menu code which is located at

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-build-a-kick-butt-css3-mega-drop-down-menu/

but I want to add another level of menu when you hover over the menu sub items it opens another menu.  I am a beginner in CSS and any help in showing me what I need to modify would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should be try [this tutorials](http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu) & you can see demo at [here](http://line25.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/css-menu/demo/index.html).